# How to insert lots of small looped videos or GIFs in HTML (thousand or more), but keep decent quality and page size?

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, gif, webp

I need to place a thousand of small GIFs (20x20 pixels or slightly bigger) in the HTML. Almost all of them are visible at once, when page is loaded. There are several ways I tried, but each one has a problem.

**Way 1.** Placing GIF images. GIFs are inefficient and heavy, so a lot of traffic will be needed to load the page. WEBP is better, but it is not supported fully in recent versions of Safari. So I made GIFs smaller, with low quality. In Safari I am loading this low quality GIFs, in other browsers I load WEBP. And it works nice, but the problem is that with a thousand of small GIFs, a user will need to load more than 600 MB for this page... So this way is... not as good. I can make them even lower in quality, but I don't want to make experience worse. Even now the quality is average.

**Way 2.** Making MP4 and embedding them into looped video tags with autostart, so they look like a GIF. This way would be AWESOME, because MP4 is much smaller in size, but it keeps good quality. The problem here is when I add even 10-15 small videos in  tags, the browser can't manage with it and starts working veeeery slowly. Each video is becoming very slow. So the experience is even worse than with low quality GIFs.

My question is – how to achieve best way in this case, keeping decent quality and low sizes for each video? Maybe I can use somehow MP4 videos in another way? Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

For scaling videos and converting to GIF/WEBP I use ffmpeg.

Comment: a large part of the problem is concurrently trying to load a thousand assets, that's never going to be a great experience. If the layout/array will be the same, can you create a single mp4 with all the gifs in place, so you only have to load a single asset?

Comment: I thought about it, but the length of each video is different. Maybe if nothing will help, I will force each video to be the same length or 2x, 3x, so I they will loop perfectly.